# Use the DNX Core framework instead of DNX 451

Tags: windows, visual-studio, asp.net-core

My `project.json` includes two frameworks:

```
"frameworks": {
  "dnx451": { },
  "dnxcore50": { }
}
```

When running the app in Visual Studio via Debug > Start without debugging, Visual Studio uses `dnx451`. How do we ask Visual Studio to use `dnxcore50` instead?

Here is what I have tried:

- **Build > Configuration Manager.** There is no option to use one framework instead of another.
- **Property Pages**. The Application, Build, and Debug areas do not offer an option to use one framework over another.

The use case is to test CoreCLR while on a system that has the full framework. How do we do this? As a last result, I could comment out `dnx451` from `project.json`, though that seems like a hack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't need to comment out `dnx451`. Instead, here is what worked.

## First, from the command line

The problem that I had initially was that on the Project Properties > Debug page, beta6 did not list .NET core as a Platform option, because I hadn't downloaded that runtime yet. So, I needed to run the following to retrieve it (don't include `-unstable` unless you want that.)

```
dnvm upgrade -unstable -runtime coreclr
```

After that, `dnvm list` now displays this. I'm wanting to target
`beta6`, `coreclr`, `x86` and that's now what's set. Perfect.

```
Active Version           Runtime Architecture Location                       Alias
------ -------           ------- ------------ --------                       -----
       1.0.0-beta4       clr     x64          C:\Users\BigFont\.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-beta4       clr     x86          C:\Users\BigFont\.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-beta4       coreclr x64          C:\Users\BigFont\.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-beta4       coreclr x86          C:\Users\BigFont\.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-beta5       clr     x86          C:\Users\BigFont\.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-beta5-12087 clr     x86          C:\Users\BigFont\.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-beta6       clr     x86          C:\Users\BigFont\.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-beta6-12085 clr     x86          C:\Users\BigFont\.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-beta6-12120 clr     x86          C:\Users\BigFont\.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-beta6-12170 clr     x86          C:\Users\BigFont\.dnx\runtimes
  *    1.0.0-beta6-12170 coreclr x86          C:\Users\BigFont\.dnx\runtimes default
```

## Now, from within Visual Studio

Go to > Project Properties > Debug. From there we can now choose the specific runtime version, platform, and architecture with which to debug the application. Since we've just downloaded beta6 coreclr, that option is now available as .NET Core.

[image: Use CoreCLR with beta6 on x86]

On save, Visual Studio will emit this setting into the project's `Properties\launchSettings.json` file as the `sdkVersion`.

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNET_ENV": "Development"
      },
      "sdkVersion": "dnx-coreclr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta6-12170"
    }
  }
}
```

Now, when we run the app from Visual Studio, it will be running with Core CLR beta6 even though our project.json lists both `dnx451` and `dnxcore50`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a hack, currently it is a standard.
Take a look here: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/conceptual-overview/dotnetcore.html#building-applications-with-net-core

You just need to erase or comment those lines.

Nowadays because of the multi-platform paradigm it seems that the ASP.NET is being more about commands and configuration files, and it less about using visual studio and interfaces.

Comment: When in Visual Studio, it looks like I can now only use the beta4 runtime with CoreCLR. Do you know of a NuGet stream from which I can download CoreCLR for beta6?

Comment: I'm currently using beta4 runtime, I believe another version are going to be release with VS 2015 in July 20